# How to make the styling only for the selected?

Tags: html, jquery, css

this the problem on my project
[image]

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='bank']").change(function(){
            var label_id = $(this).attr("id");
            $("label[for='" + label_id + "'").find("img").css("filter","grayscale(0%)");
    });
});
```

this is my code, it is correct, but the thing is ... when I chose the others, they also changed their styling while the previous ones were still styled

Comment: `<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 py-1 px-1">
       <input type="radio" id="r-pos" name="shipping" value="shipping">
       <label for="r-pos" class="shipping-item d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center p-3">
        <img src="assets/img/pos.png" alt="">
       </label>
       <div class="shipping-price text-center mt-2">
        Rp 15.375
       </div>
      </div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change css directly with jQuery, instead use class names.

For example:

css:

```css
label img.selected{
    filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='bank']").change(function(){
        $("label img").removeClass("selected"));
        var label_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $(`label[for=${label_id}] img`).addClass("selected");
    });
});
```